# How to pass a string to the body of SkyDrive API

Tags: javascript, api, onedrive

I have a code which creates the new folder in Skydrive using it's api. Its actually working. But it always creates the folder with the same name. Because the name of the folder is hardcoded.

My question is how to bind a textBox to API call so it will pass the user indicated name of the folder to API

here is the code of creating a folder:

```
  <script src="//js.live.net/v5.0/wl.js" type="text/javascript" language="javascript"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
      function createFolder_onClick() {
          WL.login({
              scope: "wl.skydrive_update"
          }).then(
          function (response) {
        WL.api({
            path: "me/skydrive",
            method: "POST",
            body: {
                "name": "This is a new folder",
                "description": "A new folder"
            }
        }).then(
            function (response) {
                document.getElementById("infoArea2").innerText =
                    "Created folder. Name: " + response.name + ", ID: " + response.id;
            },
            function (responseFailed) {
                document.getElementById("infoArea2").innerText =
                    "Error calling API: " + responseFailed.error.message;
            }
        );
    },
    function (responseFailed) {
        document.getElementById("infoArea2").innerText =
            "Error signing in: " + responseFailed.error_description;
    }
      );
      }
  </script>
```

Comment: what have you changed Friend? I can't see any difference

Answer (score 0):

You need to replace the hardcoded name of the folder by the content of your textbox. If the name of the textbox with the folder name in your code is txtFolderName, then something like this should work:

```
 <script src="//js.live.net/v5.0/wl.js" type="text/javascript" language="javascript">     </script>
  <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
      function createFolder_onClick() {
          WL.login({
              scope: "wl.skydrive_update"
          }).then(
          function (response) {
        WL.api({
            path: "me/skydrive",
            method: "POST",
            body: {
            "name": document.getElementById("txtFolderName").value,
            "description": "A new folder"
           }
        }).then(
            function (response) {
                document.getElementById("infoArea2").innerText =
                    "Created folder. Name: " + response.name + ", ID: " + response.id;
            },
            function (responseFailed) {
                 document.getElementById("infoArea2").innerText =
                    "Error calling API: " + responseFailed.error.message;
            }
        );
    },
    function (responseFailed) {
        document.getElementById("infoArea2").innerText =
            "Error signing in: " + responseFailed.error_description;
    }
      );
      }
  </script>
```